# Cannot refer to declaration with a variably modified type inside block

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

This is the snippet of my code and i am getting the above mentioned error.

```
dispatch_async(background_thread, ^{
    cameras camera[10];
    .
    .
    for(int i=0; i<ncam; i++) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0),^{
            iPoint subPoints[10];
            subPoints[0].x = camera[i].x + ((int)camera[i].mindist)*cos(camera[i].dir + (camera[i].angle)/2);
            .
            .
            .
        });
    }
});
```

cameras is actually a C-type structure and the error is with camera array. Someone please help me how to get rid off with this problem.

Comment: i have seen it but when i tried that solution, then i am getting more number of errors, i have functions also inside the for loop and those functions then started showing error

Comment: Perhaps you can update your question, show how you tried that solution and what errors you got. Otherwise we cannot see why your problem should be different from the one that I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Yours cameras located in stack, and objective-c work badly in blocks with variables that doesn't support reference counting. Try move this array inside NSObject:

```
@interface TenCameras : NSObject
{
@public
    cameras camera[10];
}
@end
```

Then yours code will be something like that:

```
dispatch_async(background_thread, ^{
    TenCameras tenCameras;
    .
    .
    for(int i=0; i<ncam; i++) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0),^{
            iPoint subPoints[10];
            subPoints[0].x = tenCameras->camera[i].x + ((int)tenCameras->camera[i].mindist)*cos(tenCameras->camera[i].dir + (tenCameras->camera[i].angle)/2);
            .
            .
            .
        });
    }
});
```